# Wordpress woocommerce - 1 consolidated payment subsite in a multisite

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, multisite, consolidation

I am running a multisite in wordpress and would like to merge all my customers' purchases to 1 subsite. The websites sell digital contentss mostly, but sell different types and run w/ considerably different logic. For one website, it has paywall that paid subscribers have access to paid contents with rolling subscription. Another website charges $1 for a permanent page access for each page. There also are websites that are linked to third party tools (Slack, Teams....) and grant contents access level membership to that service.

I've used various solutions for each website (used to be single sites), but since I now have consolidated all of them in a multisite, I wonder if there is a way to combine all transactions in one payment site, like https://payment.example.com, while my services are like https://service_number.example.com

So far, I had to run multiple queries and combined excel sheets, but if this works, for every monthly reporting, I just have to run a single query.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO and _may_ get a better response on [wp.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), although it would probably be flagged as off topic and redirected to [WC Support](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce). There are many plugins that provide global reporting across WC multisite setups, and some which sync data from multiple sites to a single site for centralised reporting.

Comment: Yup. Since multisite system is kinda new to me, I didn't have wider scope view to see what's going on. I found there are abundant addons. Should've looked at that angle before asking the question. Thx for the comment!